# Distinguishing between FIR and IIR filters from transform function

Tags: filter, dsp, math, digital-filter

I was good at this but unfortunately I have forgot almost everything... So the question is what are the steps to tell if a transform function is for IIR or FIR filter:

$$H(z) = \frac{z^3+5z^2+3z+1}{10z^3}$$

Also how to tell it it has linear phase response?

Comment: For the first part of your question an FIR filter only looks at previous inputs while an IIR filter also looks at previous output results.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on DSP.SE

Comment: @endolith Standard SE policy is NOT to migrate to Beta sites. As is this EE.SE's policy. It is on topic to both stacks, and as such, should stay here.

Comment: @Passerby I don't agree with that.  Having something on-topic on 2 different sites leads to duplicate questions and dilutes the quality of both sites.  This is 100% a DSP question and belongs on DSP.SE. http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/129/142

Comment: @endolith http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178444/should-beta-sites-be-listed-for-migration-suggestions DSP.SE is a beta site and questions should 100% not be migrated to beta sites. Also http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3384/ mainly, *We only migrate questions because they are off-topic on this site. It is perfectly possible for a question to be on-topic on multiple sites, but that is not a reason to migrate it elsewhere. The OP asked their question here, so if it's on-topic here, then it should stay here.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, note that FIR/IIR is not the same as non-recurrent/recurrent (where *recurrent* means that the output depends on previous inputs *and previous outputs*).

You can have a non-recurrent filter with infinite impulse response (e.g. \$h[n] = sinc(n/3)\$, which cannot be expressed as a recursion). And you can have a recursive construction for a FIR filter.

But, for finite-order systems, you can in general associate FIR with non-recursive forms, and IIR with recursive forms.

Your transfer function has a trivial denominator, so there is no recurrence. Divide by \$z^3\$ and you get:

$$H(z) = 0.1 + 0.5 z^{-1} + 0.3 z^{-2} + 0.1 z^{-3}$$

Trasnform back and you get the impulse response:

$$h[n] = 0.1 \delta[n] + 0.5 \delta[n-1] + 0.3 \delta[n-2] + 0.1 \delta[n-3]$$

The impulse response starts at \$n=0\$ and ends at \$n=3\$, therefore its support is finite (FIR).

If you had poles not at \$z=0\$, then you have an IIR filter. For example, if the denominator is \$\frac{\cdots}{z^2 (z-1/3)}\$, now you have a pole at \$z=1/3\$, and your recurrence equation yields (divide top and bottom by \$z^3\$ first):

$$Y(z)(1-1/3 z^{-1}) = X(z)(0.1 + 0.5 z^{-1} + 0.3 z^{-2} + 0.1 z^{-3})$$

$$y[n] - 1/3 y[n-1] = 0.1 x[n] + 0.5 x[n-1] + 0.3 x[n-2] + 0.1 x[n-3]$$

So you can see that the output \$y[n]\$ depends on previous inputs and also on the previous output \$y[n-1]\$.

Now to phase linearity:

Causal, finite-order digital filters can only be of generalized linear phase if the impulse response is symmetric (check [these slides](http://sip.cua.edu/res/docs/courses/ee515/chapter04/ch4-4.pdf) for the 4 types of symmetry; [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_phase) is undergoing copyright discussions).

So, for your original filter, the impulse response terms are `{ 0.1 0.5 0.3 0.1 }`; not symmetric, so not linear phase.

IIR causal filters will never be linear phase (impulse response starts at 0 and never ends, so no symmetry possible).